# node_module gives require is not defined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vite, laravel-9

i have a node module (vToaster) that i want to use to show error or succes notifications from my axios requests but now it randomly doesnt work anymore, and by work i mean i get this erorr and i have no idea what it could be

```
import Toaster from '@meforma/vue-toaster';
```

```
RentApp.use(Toaster);
```

This worked for like 3 weeks but now randomly i get an error:

```
    ReferenceError: require is not defined
        at Proxy.mounted (Toaster.vue:88:7)
        at callWithErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:155:22)
        at callWithAsyncErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:164:21)
        at hook.__weh.hook.__weh (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:2687:29)
        at flushPostFlushCbs (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:358:32)
        at Object.render2 [as render] (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:6206:9)
        at render (runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:1579:22)
        at mount (mount-component.js:14:3)
        at Object.show (api.js:9:17)
        at Object.success (api.js:19:19)
```

I have no idea how to fix this

I am using Laravel 9 with Vite, TailwindCss and Vue

Any help is welcome!

Comment: It would be great if you could provide a sample project on Github with your setup, as this error can occur due to the use of the type module in the package.json. It might also be related to this https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/3409. Try vite build --debug for more information.